# How to make a method that searches a parallel array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have written a working parallel array list that stores 12 countries and their corresponding populations. I am having some trouble with second piece of my assignment. I have to create a method that searches the array for the country/population that the user inputs. (For example, if the user inputs "United Kingdom", then it's corresponding population would print). However, I'm not sure how to tackle this. 
Any tips and advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InClassModule12
   {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
     String[] country = {"United States", "Brazil", "China", "Italy", "United Kingdom", "Spain", "Japan", "Germany", "France", "Turkey", "South Africa", "Argentina"};
     int[] population = { 319111000, 203462000, 1367960000, 60783711, 64105654, 46507760, 127090000, 80767000, 66050000, 76667864, 54002000, 42669500};

     for ( int i = 0; i < country.length; i++ )
     { 
       System.out.print( country[i]+ "'s population: " + " ");
        System.out.print( population[i] );
        System.out.println();
     }

  }
}
```

Edited: This is the exact assignment:
In a program you need to store the populations of 12 countries.
Define two arrays that may be used in parallel to store the names of the countries and their populations.
Write a loop that uses these arrays to print each country's name and its population.
Add a loop in your main method which asks the user running it if they would like to look up a given country's population. When they indicate “No” the program terminates.
Prompt user: What country would you like to look up?
Upon user entering something the program calls the countryLookup method.
countryLookup method accepts an argument (parameter) containing what the user entered for the country to look up. The method searches country name array for the name and upon finding it returns the corresponding population from the population array.  If it doesn't find the country simply return -1.

Comment: `if(country[i].equalsIgnoreCase(userinput)){System.out.println(population[i])}` - when iterating the country array.

Comment: 1) Find the index of the desired country in the first array. 2) Use the index on the second array. 3) Profit!

Comment: Are you allowed to use Apache's `ArrayUtils` class?  If so, there's an `indexOf` method you can use, to save having to write the code for the loop.  Let's not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @DavidWallace My teacher wants me to write the code for the loop unfortunately

Comment: No, Gianna, the assignment statement that you've pasted in doesn't specify that.  It just says that you need to write a method called `countryLookup` - it doesn't say that there has to be a loop within that method.  Honestly, if I were you, I would write that method with a call to the Apache `ArrayUtils` class.

Comment: @DavidWallace What exactly is the ArrayUtils class, could you provide some help for this?

Comment: Um, sure.  I'm a bit busy right now, but I will post an answer in a few hours, God willing, using this technique.  Unless somebody else posts it first.

Comment: If you were allowed to use something else except arrays I think you should have used a hashmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two thoughts to share with regard to this question.  The first is that it's screaming out to be programmed in an object-oriented way.  That is, there's a little collection of data, and some methods that will operate on that data.  So it makes sense to have a class whose objects actually contain that data, and whose methods do the processing; as opposed to, for example, a program where everything is static and nothing ever gets instantiated.  The `main` method can then look after the interactions with the user.  And although you CAN put `main` into the class that stores the data, it makes a good deal of sense not to.

My second thought is that for actually searching the array, it makes sense to use the Apache commons `ArrayUtils` class, which has the method `indexOf`, which is perfect for this use case.  However, I've presented an alternative in case Gianna's teacher has some objection to the use of external libraries.  Honestly, I feel that one of the key differences between an excellent Java programmer and a mediocre Java programmer is knowledge of what classes are readily available, for performing certain common tasks.

Anyway, the class that stores the data could look like this.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

public class PopulationLookup {
    private String[] countries;
    private int[] populations;

    public PopulationLookup(String[] countries, int[] populations) {
        this.countries = countries;
        this.populations = populations;
    }

    public void printAll() {
        for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            System.out.format(
                "Country: %s, population %d%n", countries[i], populations[i]);
        }
    }

    public int populationForCountry(String country) {
        int entry = ArrayUtils.indexOf(countries, country);
        if (entry != -1) {
            return populations[entry];
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't perfect.  There's no error handling around what should happen if the two arrays are not the same size, or if one of them is null, or a few other things that can go wrong.  Also, ideally, you'd copy all the array entries, rather than just references to the arrays themselves, in case the class that calls this one then starts modifying the entries of the arrays.  Those are good changes to make in version 2.

But this class demonstrates how to wrap your data up in an object, how to pass in the data via a constructor, and of course, the searching is there.

You'll need to add Apache commons lang3 to the build path to get this to work.  This is [documented here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html) and the JAR is [available from here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi).  If you really don't want to use an external library, you could change the `populationForCountry` method like this.

```
    public int populationForCountry(String country) {
        for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            if (countries[i].equals(country)) {
                return populations[i];
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Then, to complete the assignment, you need the class that contains `main`, to call this.  The important point to notice is the instantiation of the `PopulationLookup` class, passing the data that you were provided with.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InClassModule12 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] countries = {
                "United States", "Brazil", "China", "Italy", "United Kingdom", "Spain",
                "Japan", "Germany", "France", "Turkey", "South Africa", "Argentina"};
        int[] populations = {
                319111000, 203462000, 1367960000, 60783711, 64105654, 46507760, 
                127090000, 80767000, 66050000, 76667864, 54002000, 42669500};
        try( Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            PopulationLookup lookup = new PopulationLookup(countries, populations); 

            lookup.printAll();
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Would you like to look up a country?");
                String response = input.nextLine();
                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                    System.out.println("Good bye");
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("What country would you like to look up?");
                String country = input.nextLine();
                int population = lookup.populationForCountry(country);
                System.out.format("The population of %s is %d%n", country, population);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

This code uses the "try with resources" feature to ensure that the `Scanner` is closed at the end.  This was introduced in Java 7.  If you are using an earlier version of Java, then it is best to use a `finally` block to close the `Scanner`.  That would look like this.  The Java 7 code above is basically a shorter way of writing the same thing.

```
public class InClassModule12 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] countries = {
                "United States", "Brazil", "China", "Italy", "United Kingdom", "Spain",
                "Japan", "Germany", "France", "Turkey", "South Africa", "Argentina"};
        int[] populations = {
                319111000, 203462000, 1367960000, 60783711, 64105654, 46507760, 
                127090000, 80767000, 66050000, 76667864, 54002000, 42669500};

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            PopulationLookup lookup = new PopulationLookup(countries, populations); 

            lookup.printAll();
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Would you like to look up a country?");
                String response = input.nextLine();
                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                    System.out.println("Good bye");
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("What country would you like to look up?");
                String country = input.nextLine();
                int population = lookup.populationForCountry(country);
                System.out.format("The population of %s is %d%n", country, population);
            }
        } finally {
            input.close();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all of this helpful code, I cannot use an external library for my assignment, so I put this code together that you made and I understand it, thank you so much! However, I'm getting errors because there is a 'try' without 'catch' or 'finally'

Comment: Oh, I see.  This works in Java 7 (yes, I did test it).  Are you running Java 6 or earlier?

Comment: Okay, now I am getting this error:class PopulationLookup is public, should be declared in a file named PopulationLookup.java

Comment: So ... do what it says.  Put it in a file called PopulationLookup.java.

Comment: When I do that it tells me I have to put it in a file called InClassModule12

Comment: No, you'll need two files.  Put the class called PopulationLookup in a file called PopulationLookup.java.  Put the class called InClassModule12 in a file called InClassModule12. The file name for any public class has to match the name of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this untested code, where I have declared the arrays as members, implemented the method and called the method from main. Also, please, make sure you are tabulating your code better in the future:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InClassModule12 {
    public static String[] country = {"United States", "Brazil", "China", "Italy", "United Kingdom", "Spain", "Japan", "Germany", "France", "Turkey", "South Africa", "Argentina"};
    public static int[] population = { 319111000, 203462000, 1367960000, 60783711, 64105654, 46507760, 127090000, 80767000, 66050000, 76667864, 54002000, 42669500};

    public static String searchPopulation(String c) {
        for (int i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
            if (country[i].equals(c)) {
                return population[i];
            }
        }
        return "Not found";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        for ( int i = 0; i < country.length; i++ ) { 
            System.out.print( country[i]+ "'s population: " + " ");
            System.out.print( population[i] );
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println(searchPopulation((new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine()));

    }
}
```

Comment: For this one, I am getting an incompatable types error with constructor Scanner()

Comment: Is there any Scanner input here? Please help me complete this code I am stuck

Comment: @GiannaCaruso, you are right, I forgot to pass System.in for the Scanner constructor. I have edited my code and added the fix.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still not working? There is still no input.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the user submitted country in your array to use the corresponding index :

```
for ( int i = 0; i < country.length; i++ ) { 
    if (country[i].equals(user_input)) {
        System.out.println(country[i] + "'s population: " + population[i]);
        break; // gets you out of the loop
    }
}
```

It's also a good programming habit to save an array's length in a variable as such :

```
for ( int i = 0, l = country.length ; i < l ; i++ ) {
```

Or else the array's length has to be calculated on each iteration.

Comment: Is this going into a method or is it in the main method? I'm sorry, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

There is no code in your example for actually collecting input, which leads me to believe you are not familiar with getting user input in Java. The `Scanner` class is a convenient way to handle this, and you can read more on that here: [Java Scanner Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html).

You can use `Scanner`'s `nextLine()` function to get a line of user input.

For example:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner();
String userInput = kb.nextLine();
int length = country.length;

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   if(userInput.equals(country[i]))
   {
      System.out.println(userInput + "'s " + " population is: " + population[i]);
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
You can place this inside some method, perhaps `searchPopulation(String country)`, and call it inside a loop in `main` such as:

```
while(userChoice == true)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter a country: ");
    String userInput = kb.nextLine();
    searchPopulation(userInput);

   //Check if the user would like to keep going here
}
```

Of course, you would have to modify the first code example so that the name of the `String` matches the name provided in the method declaration, and remove the user input from the first code example since you are now handling it in the `while` loop.

**EDIT:** You may have something like this in your program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass
{
    static String country[] = {"United States", "Brazil", "China", "Italy", "United Kingdom", "Spain", "Japan",              "Germany", "France", "Turkey", "South Africa", "Argentina"};;
    static int population[] = { 319111000, 203462000, 1367960000, 60783711, 64105654, 46507760, 127090000, 80767000, 66050000, 76667864, 54002000, 42669500};    

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       boolean userChoice = true;
       String userInput = "";
       Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

       while(userChoice == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a country: ");
            userInput = kb.nextLine();
            searchPopulation(userInput);

           //Check if the user would like to keep going here
        }

       kb.close();
    }

    public static void searchPopulation(String userInput)
    {
        int length = country.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
           if(userInput.equals(country[i]))
           {
              System.out.println(userInput + "'s " + " population is: " + population[i]);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

With this, every time the loop iterates you ask the user for a country, then pass the country they entered to the method `searchPopulation` which searches for and outputs the population if the country is a match.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this code. But I need a method to search the code for the country. I know how to collect input but I am unsure how to create a loop that calls a method that searches an array.

Comment: @GiannaCaruso I am not sure what you are asking here. You can place something like this inside a method that accepts a 'String' and invoke it wherever you like, perhaps within a loop in 'main' that collects user input and checks it repeatedly until the user would like to stop. Could you please clarify, is putting it inside the method what you are unsure about?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I added the exact assignment language to the question if that helps. I need to write a method that searches the country array and outputs the population for said country. I also need a loop that calls that method in the main.

Comment: @GiannaCaruso I have modified my original answer. Hopefully this can help you.

Comment: Okay, I am so sorry for my simpleness. But could you please explain to me where and how this method is working. Is that method searching for anything?

Comment: @GiannaCaruso It seems you do not understand how basic program control (going from the main method to other methods, etc) works. I will modify my answer further but I highly suggest you seek help from your instructor to better understand what is going on within the code.

Comment: There are many errors in the code in this answer.  In fact, it fails to compile.  I would strongly recommend to the respondent that he/she tests his/her code before posting it here.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thank you. I have fixed the errors and updated my answer. I will be more careful about that in the future.

Comment: That looks a lot better.  Thank you for sorting it out.  I just fixed the one typo that you missed.

Comment: The code still doesn't compile, I don't even see where the user is getting input. Could you please help we figure this out?

Comment: @GiannaCaruso The code compile and works for me, the only thing that is missing is checking for user input (where the comment specifies, intentionally left blank as an exercise for you). Here you might ask the user if they want to continue, have them enter yes/no, and set the userChoice = false if they say no.

Comment: Okay, would I make a new variable for this? Is it going into the while loop for userInput = true? I'm sorry I'm just confused

Comment: Also, this code does not print out all of the countries along with their populations, which I need

Comment: Yes, you need a new variable to hold the user input. Once you've created it, use the Scanner to get input inside the while loop to see if they would like to continue (earlier in the while loop you can see user input being placed in a String). You may also have this new code contained inside another loop (all still in the while loop) that validates the input, i.e. checks to make sure the user actually entered "yes" or "no" rather than some random text or numbers. Regarding printing the countries and populations, a simple loop going through the arrays with a print statement would work for this.

Comment: I still cannot figure out how to write this code so that the country lookup keeps going as the user enters Yes.

Comment: Also, what kind of loop? I have a loop written in my original code that I posted, however this gives me like 50 errors when I try to put it into the new code.

Comment: I'm begging you, please show me how to ask for input in the loop, I've been at this for hours and I cannot get this assignment.